# Is the rank of $x$ within a set of iid draws from the same distribution uniform?

Tags: distributions, ranks

I have one realization $x$ drawn from any random distribution. I also have a large set $X$ of other (iid) draws from the very same distribution.
Now I'm interested in the *distribution of the rank of $x$ in $X$.*

My intuition is that this would be uniform, but I couldn't find a proof of that.

**Background**:
In the context of a Fisher re-randomization test, I'd like to obtain a p-value for the null that a number is drawn from a certain distribution. I can draw from that distribution and was now thinking I could just do another 1000 draws, look at the relative rank of my number in the distribution of these draws, and use that as a p-value:
$$p^{rightsided} = rrank(x,X)$$
$$p^{leftsided} = 1-rrank(x,X)$$
$$p^{twosided} = 1-|rrank(x,X)-0.5|*2$$
(where $rrank(x,X)$ is the relative rank of $x$ in $X$)

This would obviously only have power against the alternative that the original number stems from a distribution with more extreme values being more likely.

Comment: Can you provide more context for this? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I've rewritten my question entirely, does it make more sense now?

Comment: That does help a lot. I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: Your question amounts to saying you have $n+1$ iid values from a common distribution, and asking for the distribution of their ranks.  *If ties have no chance of occurring,* the ranks will be $1,2,\ldots,n+1$, which obviously is uniform. If ties can occur, the answer depends on how you rank tied values.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the specific $x$ is prespecified, its rank should be uniform.  Thats because all possible permutations of $n$ iid variables are equally probable.

Comment: ... as long as we assume the original distribution is continuous.

Comment: ... yes, and if we have a discrete distribution, if in addition we assume that ties are broken randomly.